# Are there apps that record the screen and take videos from the camera simultaneously in the background while a third app that uses the camera runs?

Tags: screen-capture, android-augmented-reality

For an augmented reality app, I must record screen and camera simultaneously. I found apps that record the screen while I run my augmented reality app. However, I couldn't find apps that record a video from the camera while letting my augmented reality app work normally as both these apps need to use the camera simultaneously.